# Selenium - OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to keep my automated chrome windows open, but they close with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Duma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 841, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\Duma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1193, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Using **Selenium** and my **Python script** looks like this:

```
login_url='https://www.life4laptop.com/index.php?route=account/login'
url='https://www.life4laptop.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=samsung'
list=[]
driver=webdriver.Chrome(crm_path, chrome_options=options)
driver.get(login_url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("input-email")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['life4laptop']['username'])
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("input-password")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['life4laptop']['password'])
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/input[@type='submit']")
elem.click()
driver.get(url)

driver2=webdriver.Chrome(crm_path, chrome_options=options)
driver2.get(login_url)
elem = driver2.find_element_by_id("input-email")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['life4laptop']['username'])
elem = driver2.find_element_by_id("input-password")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(x['life4laptop']['password'])
elem = driver2.find_element_by_xpath("//form/input[@type='submit']")
elem.click()
driver2.get(url)
#driver.close()
#driver.quit()
```

Any clues **why**, and **how to get it working**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been because I quit my script. When the script is contentiously running, it's fine.

Answer (score 7):

If you came in here wondering why this error showed up on your `tearDown(self)` method, it could be because you are using `driver.close()` instead of `driver.quit()`.

You can refer to this thread ([here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4505)) for an explanation on the difference between the two, but to sum it up: `driver.close()` closes the tab/window but not the driver instance, whereas `driver.quit()` does the latter.

Hope it helps anyone else stepping in here looking for an answer to this issue.